# Is there a function/Macro in Linux Kernel to get current preemption status on smp machine?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel

In my project I use `get_cpu()` and `put_cpu()` to disable and enable the preemption in the kernel on a `smp` machine.

Is there a `safe way` to get the current preemption status in an smp machine i.e. whether the preemption is turned on or off.

Comment: I think the seconds paragraph is missing a word :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preempt_count`() returns current thread's preemption count. 0 value means that preemtion is allowed.

Usually, you shouldn't request preemtion status unless for the selfcheck. If some block of code requires preemtion to be disabled, it should be wrapped with `preempt_disable()`/`preempt_enable()` calls (or their alternatives).